# Installing Skype, Steam, Wine problems

Tags: wine, steam, skype

i'm new on Linux with Elementary OS.

I want to install Skype, Steam and Wine but i can't install these.
When i try to this:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
sudo apt-get install steam
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I'm getting this errors:
http://hastebin.com/hegejuhiyu.sql

How can i install this programs?

Comment: Please break these into separate questions. Have you tried installing the dependencies according to the error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, the simple solution is:
just go to appcenter and search for gbedi package installer.

If you want to do it the hard way try

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get -i /yourpathhere/skype.deb
```

Comment: Thanks but i installed Skype Alpha.

Comment: And installed Steam with some errors... :(

Also now i need to install Wine.

Comment: yeah honestly, i have no idea how to install wine, for me it kinda worked by accident :-)

Comment: well, i had to reinstall because my hard drive died and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: oops, wrong thread. sorry